# Why is the projection of a vector V onto a span W, independent of the orthogonal basis of W.

Tags: linear-algebra, projective-geometry, orthonormal, projective-space, orthogonality

Very straightforward question. I have read time and again in my book that it is independent but I don't understand why?

Wouldn't changing the basis mean changing the length of the projection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I take the leaning tower of Pisa, and hang a weight from the top to the ground, then I'm projecting it orthogonally into the plane of the ground.  The point that that weight touches the ground is the same whether I choose to use a pair of basis vectors where one is a meter pointing north and the other is a meter pointing west or if I choose to use a pair of basis vectors where one is foot in NW and the other is a foot NE.

The physical place that the projection reaches is the same.  The coefficients of those basis vectors is different.  I think you're getting confused and thinking that the coefficients give the length.

Comment: I completely understand your answer as to the lengths of vectors that span the space, but what if the subspace can vary between angles. In that case wont a subspace pointing to, say the Sun, have a different projection of the tower than a subspace on ground (?)

Thanks a lot Joel! I got the answer by reading your 2nd paragraph! Much appreciated!

Comment: To be clear - if we say we will do an orthogonal projection onto the ground, that uniquely sets things.  If we keep talking about the ground, but choose a different angle to project at, that's not orthogonal.  If we choose to project to a different plane, it's a different plane, and who knows.

Comment: Yep, my understanding of orthogonal basis was weak but I just revised the concept. Would have up voted but low on reputation. Thanks a lot though!

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that when you say "projection", it is expressed as a vector of coordinates relative to the basis.

It would not change the length, as you only consider orthogonal bases. By definition, orthogonal bases consist of vectors of length $1$, so the coordinates relative to all bases will have the same length.

Comment: Just a note, orthogonal bases need not have length 1.  Orthonormal means orthogonal and length 1.

Comment: AFAIK the term "orthogonal basis" means "a basis where each vector is orthogonal to all others, and has norm 1". This terminology seemed weird to me too, but this is what I encountered in most of the literature.

Comment: You should double check that.